# How does one specify physical CPU ids in openmpi 1.6.4+ rankfiles?

Tags: mpi, openmpi, affinity, hyperthreading

The latest (`v1.8.3`) OpenMPI documentation specifies that rankfiles must now use the *logical* cpu IDs reported by `hwloc` rather than the *physical* IDs, see the last sentence in the `Rankfiles` section of the `mpirun` documentation [here](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man1/mpirun.1.php):

> Starting with Open MPI v1.7, all socket/core slot locations are be
>   specified as logical indexes (the Open MPI v1.6 series used physical
>   indexes). You can use tools such as HWLOC’s "lstopo" to find the
>   logical indexes of socket and cores.

I've noticed a few questions on this site (notably [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074248/using-hwloc-physical-id-to-build-mpi-rankfile) and the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749182/assign-two-mpi-processes-per-core)) that indicate that one can specify physical cpu ids in an openMPI rankfile by prefixing the id with a `p`.  For example:

```
rank 0=localhost slot=p0
rank 1=localhost slot=p8
rank 2=localhost slot=p1
rank 3=localhost slot=p9
```

To request physical cpu id `0` for rank `0`, physical cpu id `8` for rank `1` etc...

I've tried searching for this syntax in the OpenMPI docs to no avail. I've also tried to have someone actually try constructing a rankfile this way in OpenMPI `1.6.4`, which he reported also doesn't work.

What version(s) of OpenMPI does this syntax work with?  Is it documented anywhere?  What is the formal syntax?

Comment: Use `lstopo -l` to get the logical IDs. Then put in the rankfile `slot=logicalID`.

Comment: Thanks.  I realize that you can get the logical IDs this way, and that may be fine if you're creating your rankfiles manually.  However, if you're auto-generating the rankfile as part of a job execution setup then you'll need to do a call to remotely call `lstopo` for each host referenced in the rankfile.  That's just not acceptable for our use case.  That's why I'm curious about the versions of openmpi that support the `p` notation for specifying physical ids, and the specific syntax of that notation.

Comment: May [the source](https://svn.open-mpi.org/trac/ompi/browser/trunk/opal/mca/hwloc/base/hwloc_base_util.c#L1189) be with you, or, in that particular case, against you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Hristo Iliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374437/hristo-iliev) for pointing me in the direction of the appropriate code.  It seems the function [`hwloc_base_slot_list_parse`](https://svn.open-mpi.org/source/s?refs=opal_hwloc_base_slot_list_parse) appeared in the open-mpi code from version `1.8`.

Tracing back through the code I arrived at the [`orte_rmaps_rankfile_parse`](https://svn.open-mpi.org/source/s?refs=orte_rmaps_rank_file_parse) function which seems to go back as far as version `1.3`.  Looking into the history of this function, we find that the following code snippet appears from the version `1.5` branch on in the section parsing the slot list:

```
/* we no longer support physical mappings */
if ('P' == value[0] || 'p' == value[0]) {
    orte_show_help("help-rmaps_rank_file.txt", "not-supported", true, rankfile);
    rc = ORTE_ERR_SILENT;
    ORTE_ERROR_LOG(rc);
    goto unlock;
}
```

So from this I conclude that the answer to my question is that the `p` notation is supported in OpenMPI versions below `1.5`

*Edit:* I also found [this message](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2012/02/18381.php) in the `Open MPI Users` mailing list which seems to support my findings.