# How to run an mpi executable from julia

Tags: mpi, julia

I want to call an MPI exectable from Julia in a Jupyter notebook.

Doing

```
cmd = Cmd(`mpiexec -np 4 name_of_executable`)
run(cmd)
```

creates 4 processes, but they all use 25% cpu on one core. Is there a way to have it run 100% on four separate cores?

Comment: Is this the same as if you run `mpiexec -np 4 name_of_executable` from the command line?

Comment: also is your environment and OS 64 bit / multi core......? check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749182/assign-two-mpi-processes-per-core#answer-11749530) , might be related

Comment: Just a remark, no need for `Cmd(\`mpiexec -np 4 name_of_executable\`)`, `\`mpiexec -np 4 name_of_executable\`` is enough.

Comment: @AlexanderMorley No, if I run the command from the command line, I get four processes, each taking up 100%, not 25% each on one core

Comment: @AntJavaDev I have tried two suggestions from the answer you link to. Adding the option "--map-by core -bind-to-core" to the command results in "A request was made to bind to that would result in binding more processes than cpus on a resource:   #processes:  1  #cpus:       1" even though this is a multicore machine.  Adding "-npersocket 4" gives the same result as before, 4 processes with 25% cpu each.

Comment: I also get the same result (4 processes with 25% cpu each) when issuing these commands from the REPL.

Comment: then maybe when being invoked from a 'third party' process , looks like its getting restricted to only 1 core per process as it doesnt really execute mpiexec. cant see any suggestion whether Julia runs on all cores