# Assigning N cores per MPI rank

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to assign N cores per MPI rank. I'm running an application with 256 MPI ranks, and I would like to assign 16 cores per MPI rank.

The solutions I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749182/assign-two-mpi-processes-per-core) are useful but want me to use a `rankfile` and this gets tedious after a certain number of rank-core relationship.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Open MPI, you can

```
mpirun --map-by node:PE=16 ...
```

Comment: One question : when this is done how can one access the individual processors of each rank?

Comment: What do you mean ? The MPI task is bound on 16 cores. It is up to the app to create threads and bind them to the 15 other cores. The OpenMP runtime can do that if you use hybrid MPI+OpenMP

Comment: yes that was what I was missing ... hybrid parallel program. This especially is useful only when the program is hybrid parallel right ? Please correct me if I am wrong.