# input to deterministically bind Open MPI ranks to NUMA node cores

Tags: mpi, openmpi

Trying to bind an Open MPI rank to every core on a NUMA node machine.
The machine has 2 nodes, each with 12 cores.
The nodes doesnt have name, so I'm not able to do `--host a:12,b:12`
Also I want to bind extra ranks deterministically onto specific cores, how to do it when oversubscribe?

First question is: **How to bind 24 ranks onto NUMA node cores? With one rank per core**
`mpirun -n 24 --bind-to numa --report-bindings ./app`
This command will return `There are not enough slots available in the system`, while if I do `lscpu`, the output says `CPU(s): 24, NUMA node(s): 2`

Second question is: **If I want to bind 27 ranks (oversubscribe) on the same NUMA machine, how to do it deterministically?**
When I want to oversubscribe 3 ranks, how to do it so that the extra 3 ranks will always bind to the same 3 cores each time I run the application?

Comment: 24 CPUs reported by `lscpu` can be 24 cores or 24 threads, look at `Thread(s) per core` to figure this out. If there are indeed 2 threads per core, you can `mpirun --use-hwthread-cpus ...` to have Open MPI consider one slot = one thread (instead of the default 1 slot = 1 core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `-cpu-list` on a 32 physical core NUMA node, [0-23] `cpu-list` will only bind 16 cores. Adding `--use-hwthread-cpus` will allocate MPI ranks to [0-23] as it is.

```
mpirun -n 24 -cpu-list 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 --bind-to cpu-list:ordered --use-hwthread-cpus ./app
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to bind 24 ranks onto NUMA node cores? With one rank per core

First, as @Gilles pointed out: Make sure that your 24 cores are actual physical cores and not hyperthreads.

The most secure (and also most tedious) is to give the ordered processor list to the `mpirun` command.
For you that would be:

```
mpirun -np 24 --report-bindings --cpu-list 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 --bind-to cpu-list:ordered ./app
```

This gives you full control over which process is spawned where, which can be really helpful when certain processes communicate a lot. You can make sure they are close to each other from a hardware point of view. Or you want to avoid that certain cores are used, because other jobs are running on them.

> If I want to bind 27 ranks (oversubscribe) on the same NUMA machine, how to do it deterministically?

First, that is something that should generally be avoided in production code. Especially for code, where each process does the same. It kills your efficiency, since your program is only as fast as the slowest core!

That said, you should be able to use a rankfile for that, further described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749182/assign-two-mpi-processes-per-core) and [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man1/mpirun.1.php#sect13)

For example, lets say you want to pin 4 processes on core 0:

`rankfile`:

```
rank 0=localhost slot=0:0
rank 1=localhost slot=0:0
rank 2=localhost slot=0:0
rank 3=localhost slot=0:0
```

And then

```
mpirun -np 4 --report-bindings -rf rankfile ./app
```

Comment: The machine I'm using has indeed 24 physical cores. 
"cpu-list:ordered" is not recognized. I'm using the current Open MPI master, which "--bind-to" should replace "cpu-list"?

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean. I am using OpenMPI as well and the command, exactly like it is written in the answer works without issues. Could you confirm again, that it does not work for you?
If it does not work, could you provide the error output and also the output of `lscpu` ?

Comment: The exact command does not work as the exact error is `The specified bind-to directive is not recognized:

  Directive: cpu-list:ordered
  Valid directives: none:hwthread:core:l1cache:l2cache:l3cache:numa:package

Please check for a typo or ensure that the directive is a supported one.`

Comment: This is a feature introduced in OpenMPI version 4.0, so you are running something prior (3.X). You can check with `mpirun --version`. Considering version 5.0 was released already, you should consider upgrading the MPI version used. This is a good idea in general, but would also enable the cpu-list:ordered

Comment: I'm running the latest Open MPI main branch. `mpirun --version` returns mpirun (Open MPI) 5.1.0a1. Should this feature be in the main branch already?

Comment: The latest master does not have "--bind-to cpu-list:ordered", but the 4.1.7 release does have this feature.
I tried `mpirun -n 24 -cpu-list 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 ./app` but `There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 24
slots that were requested by the application`.

Comment: given the `lscpu` output as 
`Architecture:  x86_64
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s): 32
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-31
Thread(s) per core: 2
Core(s) per socket: 16
Socket(s): 1
NUMA node(s): 2
`

Comment: `mpirun --report-bindings -cpu-list 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 --bind-to cpu-list:ordered ./app` will have `mpirun` see 16 cores, but not 24